# Using a positive phrase to explain a negative one vs. the opposite

Tags: negation

Are the two sentences bellow grammatically correct and semantically equivalent?

> 1. I don't think it rained yesterday.
> 2. I think it didn't rain yesterday.

I was told that sentence 2 is grammatically incorrect and that I can't use a positive phrase to explain a negative event. I have to use phrase 1 instead.

Comment: Whoever told you #2 is incorrect is wrong.  You can certainly use a positive phrasing to express that something didn't happen.  I really wonder where people get some of these "rules" from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sentence 1 is more common, but sentence 2 is 100% correct.